# How to do relationship automatically between entities in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have made a website with Joomla 2.5.x and now I am working on the ER diagram of the database.

I found MySQL Workbench that automatically creates it. I tried but it shows only entities.

How to do relation automatically (because database of my website is too complex)?

Comment: See Mike's answer. Also please note that core Jooma! tables don't implement relationships. They are done on the software part and not enforced in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Relationships can only be displayed in Workbench (WB) if they exist, that is, there are foreign keys defined. WB will pick up any foreign key and creates a relationship in the diagram automatically.

Comment: yeaa..thank you to all for reply..I also checked the same thing that there is no foreign key in any of the table...